# QML app released with windeployqt not showing UI

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have released a windows app using windeployqt. It works everywhere except on one PC. On that PC (Windows 10 Pro) the app runs (I can see it from the Task Manager) but UI is not shown.
These are the steps I do to release the app:

```
rmdir /S /Q install
mkdir install
copy "build\Desktop_Qt_5_14_2_MinGW_64_bit\Release\release\MyApp.exe" install
C:\Qt\5.14.2\mingw73_64\bin\windeployqt.exe --qmldir qml install\MyApp.exe
copy "C:\Qt\5.14.2\mingw73_64\bin\libgcc_s_seh-1.dll" install
copy "C:\Qt\5.14.2\mingw73_64\bin\libstdc++-6.dll" install
copy "C:\Qt\5.14.2\mingw73_64\bin\libwinpthread-1.dll" install
pause
```

Am I missing something? Thank you

Comment: If you run the app from the cli does it output anything ?

Comment: Unfortunately no